# Why isn't my MacBook sleeping?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I'm trying to figure out why my MacBook isn't sleeping, but `pmset` doesn't fully clarify the source of the issue. At the surface level, it seems to be three daemons (powerd, bluetoothd, sharingd) that prevent sleep, but I still don't understand why they're actually preventing sleep. I have a Magic Keyboard and Magic Mouse connected, but both are well-charged. As for powerd and sharingd, I have even less of an idea. Any advice on how to allow my MacBook to sleep automatically under regular usage would be appreciated.

Here's the output of `pmset -g`.

```
System-wide power settings:
 SleepDisabled      0
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by powerd, bluetoothd, sharingd)
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10 (display sleep prevented by Music)
 tcpkeepalive         1
 powermode            0
 womp                 1
```

And also `pmset -g assertions`.

```
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    1
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  1
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 351(powerd): [0x0007a5b1000193e4] 02:00:07 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Powerd - Prevent sleep while display is on"  
   pid 351(powerd): [0x0000002f00088022] 207:29:48 ExternalMedia named: "com.apple.powermanagement.externalmediamounted"  
   pid 400(bluetoothd): [0x0007c1a60001a675] 00:00:50 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.BTStack"  
   pid 435(coreaudiod): [0x0007c1d80001a3c0] 00:00:00 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.audio.BuiltInSpeakerDevice.context.preventuseridlesleep"  
    Created for PID: 1836. 
   pid 435(coreaudiod): [0x0007c18500018bf9] 00:01:23 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.audio.AVVCAggregateDevice-8268-282475249.context.preventuseridlesleep"  
    Created for PID: 8268. 
   pid 435(coreaudiod): [0x0007c18500018c88] 00:01:23 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.audio.BuiltInSpeakerDevice.context.preventuseridlesleep"  
    Created for PID: 900. 
   pid 977(sharingd): [0x0007c0010001a605] 00:07:51 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Handoff"  
   pid 409(WindowServer): [0x0007a5b1000993e0] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:100023550 service:AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2 product:Magic Keyboard with Touch ID eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 600 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 53047(rcd): [0x0007c1850009a66c] 00:01:24 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.rcdevent"  
    Timeout will fire in 516 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 900(Music): [0x0007c1850001a66d] 00:01:23 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.Music.playback"  
   pid 900(Music): [0x0003adb2000598c5] 92:21:47 PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep named: "com.apple.Music.playback"  
   pid 49533(mds): [0x0007bf67000ba55c] 00:10:25 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.power"  
   pid 892(cloudd): [0x0007c1d60001a679] 00:00:02 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "NSURLSessionTask 9003E01A-EB1D-4545-AF85-DDB969F05E93"  
    Timeout will fire in 10797 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 892(cloudd): [0x0007c1d60001a67a] 00:00:02 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "NSURLSessionTask 9003E01A-EB1D-4545-AF85-DDB969F05E93"  
    Timeout will fire in 10797 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 892(cloudd): [0x0007c1d70001a67b] 00:00:01 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "NSURLSessionTask 0DD1D0C2-8CDE-4BFF-9017-5A3B61B6B84C"  
    Timeout will fire in 10798 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 892(cloudd): [0x0007c1d70001a67c] 00:00:01 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "NSURLSessionTask 0DD1D0C2-8CDE-4BFF-9017-5A3B61B6B84C"  
    Timeout will fire in 10798 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
Kernel Assertions: 0x10c=USB,BT-HID,MAGICWAKE
   id=513  level=255 0x4=USB creat=19/01/2023, 01:37 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.00200000 owner=EXTERNAL_USB
   id=514  level=255 0x4=USB creat=19/01/2023, 01:49 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.01200000 owner=G-Drive Mobile USB
   id=515  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE creat=19/01/2023, 01:40  mod=23/01/2023, 13:29 description=en0 owner=IOSkywalkNetworkBSDClient
   id=1293  level=255 0x8=BT-HID creat=25/01/2023, 15:19 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=AppleHSBluetoothDevice
   id=1571  level=255 0x8=BT-HID creat=27/01/2023, 17:04 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=AppleHSBluetoothDevice
```

Comment: It tells you that sleep is prevented because the display is on, the Music app is preventing it (possibly you have something playing or queued up) and Handoff is running.  Have you tried closing the apps you are using that utilize these features (i.e. quit the Music app)?  What were the results?

Comment: @Allan If I quit the Music app, the line about display sleep being prevented disappears, but I still get `sleep prevented by powerd, bluetoothd, sharingd`. Doesn't Handoff run passively in the background? I was under the impression it shouldn't display sleep. I wouldn't even know how to quit that.

Comment: In the order of services you listed...your display, a Bluetooth device, and file sharing is preventing sleep.  Check your power settings for "display sleep" then your BT device list to see what is connected and finally, check your file sharing settings.  The display is easy.  If you are streaming *anything* to/from a BT device, it will suspend sleep.  It's not a keyboard where it's attached but can be idle (nobody typing).  Finally, if you've set up sharing and someone is attached, it will prevent your computer from sleeping.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for your suggestions. For powerd, the only relevant setting I see in System Preferences is "Prevent automatic sleeping on the power adapter when the display is off", and that it unchecked. I thought it might be a 3rd-party app like Amphetamine, but quitting that doesn't help. For bluetoothd, I've established it's my Magic Keyboard (not my Magic Mouse) – but ought that really to prevent sleep? For sharingd, I figured out that restarting the SMB service temporarily solves that particular issue, though it shortly after reappears.

Comment: Re the last point, I can't find a good source for how to list connected SMB clients on macOS.

Comment: To see who is logged in, go to *Network* in *Activity Monitor*.  Alternatively, you can use the `last |grep “logged-in”` command to see who is currently logged nto your computer.

Comment: @Allan Thanks. Oddly, both methods show no one as logged in. (I didn't know SMB users showed up there until now, by the way!)